# Nested loop: multiple model parameters

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, time

I am working on a code which will calculate a statistical model with multiple parameters, which I want to change on the way. Then, on the basis of performance of models I will choose the best one.

I wrote such a chuck of pseudo-code which illustrates the problem:

```
## vectors with values of parameters

const1 <- c(300, 500)
const2 <-  c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
const3 <- c(30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130)

## loop counter

i = 1

for (j in 1:length(const1)){
  for (k in 1:length(const2)){
    for (l in 1:length(const3)){

      ## i-th model

      model <- stat.model(x = train,
                          y = target,
                          param1 = const1,
                          param2 = const2,
                          param3 = const3)

      ## ... outputing model results to a data table

      ## printing the number of iteration

      cat("iteration =", i)
      i <- i+1

      ## calling garbage collector to assure free space in RAM

      gc()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I use nested "for", loops which is probably not the most efficient way of programming in R. Is there any way to shorten the time of processing (and possibly save the legibility of the code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Speed of `for` loops in `R`.

In `R`, the major issue with using nested `for`-loops is readability (and perhaps also allocation of memory). So, if you know the length of your output in advance, either create a storage object of this length using `vector()` or simply call `lapply` or `vapply` instead. The speed of the `for`-loop itself is not a serious issue in `R`.

## Readability

For your example, you can simply create all possible combinations that you want to use in advance by calling `expand.grid` on your three vectors, for which you are using three different, nested `for`-loops like this:

```
combis <- expand.grid(const1 = const1,
                      const2 = const2,
                      const3 = const3)

combis <- combis[order(combis$const1, combis$const2, combis$const3), ]

lapply(seq_len(nrow(combis)), FUN = function(i) {
  model <- stat.model(x = train,
                      y = target,
                      param1 = combis[i, "const1"],
                      param2 = combis[i, "const2"],
                      param3 = combis[i, "const3"])
  model
})
```

## Parallelization

If you have multiple cores at your disposal, you can easily convert any `lapply` "loop" into a parallelized version by using `mclapply` from the [parallel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) package instead. Then you can specify the number of cores via the `mc.cores` argument. This allows you to parallelize your loops with little additional effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is probably one mistake in your code: I had to change `seq_along(nrow(combis)` to `seq(1, nrow(combis)` in order to make it work.

Comment: You are right. I've changed `seq_along` to `seq_len`, which does the same thing as your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize your opperations with lapply statements, for your pseudo code

```
model <- function(x,y,z){x+y+z}

lapply(const1,function(x){
  lapply(const2,function(y){
    lapply(const3,function(z){model(x,y,z)})})})
```